# JQuery inside here-doc not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, cgi, heredoc

Is it possible to include JQuery in the here-doc section of perl.
I tried but no success.
Here is my code.

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();print header();print start_html("JQuery in perl");

print <<JS;
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
 });
});
//--></script>

<p>Click to hide</p>
<p>Click to hide</p>
<p>Click to hide</p>
</body>
JS
print end_html();
```

But when I write a javascript function, it works fine

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();print header();print start_html("hello");
print <<JS;
<script><!--
function show() {alert("Hello");}
//--></script>
<input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="show()">
</body>
JS
print end_html();
```

Am I missing something obvious here ?Please suggest.

Comment: Should work. What happens if you call `jQuery` directly. Eg: `jQuery.method()` instead of `$()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A here-doc works similar to a double-quoted string: variables are evaluated. As `$(` is actually a [variable in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) it will get replaced by the process' real group ID. Escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Or use a 'single-quoted HEREDOC'.  `print <<'JS';`

Comment: Or use a templating system.