# jQuery .get() and Perl not functioning together

Tags: jquery, perl, get

I'm having a little trouble with something simple I think.  I've got a Perl script that already contains a bunch of functioning JQuery.  I was hoping to use .blur and .get to run an email validation sub in Perl immediately when the user leaves the email address field.  However, I can't seem to connect a Perl script and the JQuery call together.  So I've simplified as much as I can just to try to get it to function.  Basically, the user leaves the input field, the script is called, simply prints something and I have Jquery through an alert.

JQuery

```
$('#billemail').blur(function() {
    $.get('ajax_email_check.pl', { 'email': $('#billemail').val() }, function(data) {
        alert ("Billing email is "+data+"!");
    });
});
```

Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
require "./lib/servervars.pl";
require "./lib/common.pl";

my $email_address = param('email');

#my $email_valid = &check_email($email_address);

#if ($email_valid) {
#    $output = "Success";
#} 
#else {
#    $output = "Fail";
#}

print "Success";
```

Of course if I remove the .get line and closing tags, the alert is triggered upon the field losing focus.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show the actual code, and how you have the jQuery embedded?

Comment: This might help: [jquery-inside-here-doc-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958759/jquery-inside-here-doc-not-working)

Comment: There is already a bunch of JQuery in my script and it's all functioning fine.  Also, the above code does not break my functioning JQuery.  It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the problem? What errors are you getting? Is that `alert` call valid? Shouldn't it look like `alert("String" + data);`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors is the problem lol.  Just nothing happens.  If I take out the .get line and the closing tags, but leave alert, alert is thrown when the field loses focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Perl script (at least the version you've posted) doesn't output a content type header. That's the very least a CGI script must output: the response headers, an empty line signalling the end of the headers, and optionally the content (the string `success` in your case), e.g.

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
if (email_is_valid()) {
  print "success";
} else {
  print "error";
}
```

Comment: You are the friggin man Moritz. Thank you so much!  This fixed the issue.  Once again Perl has humbled me.

Comment: You should really have [CGI](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER "perldoc CGI") create the headers for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you escaped the `$` here?

```
$.get('ajax_email_check.pl', { 'email': \$('#billemail').val() }

                                       ^^^^^
```

At the very least that'll probably prevent you from getting your value out of the `billemail` element (input?).

More importantly, you're mis-matching quotes, so your JS at large is invalid:

```
alert ("Billing email is '+data+'!");   // <-- Need double-quotes
                        ^^^    ^^^
```

Try fixing that and see if you get a better result.

Comment: its in a perl script. i meant to strip that before posting. ive got all my $ escaped in between my script tags

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I swapped them to double quotes and no dice.  I updated my code above to reflect what I'm doing.